# Rerender Stripe Element when client secret changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I am trying to create a cart page, in which the client/customer can edit/remove cart items(items in the cart). So when they edit/remove items in the cart the total changes.

Currently, if I add items to cart and enter the cart page the payment gateway will be shown with the total (let's say its $100). And then I edit the cart items (the price increase/decreases, let's say now the price is $50). Now if I press "Pay Now" the payment gateway will charge me $100 and not $50.

I want to get the stripe payment gateway to change the cart total in the transaction.

code below is the code from PaymentGateway.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import CheckoutForm from "./CheckoutForm";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import axios from "axios";
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const PaymentGateway = ({ cart, handleCart, handleValidation }) => {
    //set cart total and watch for changes in the variable to rerender component
    const [cartTotal, setCartTotal] = useState(cart.total);

    // Stripe functions
    const [stripePromise, setStripePromise] = useState(() =>
        loadStripe('stripe public key' )
    );
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState("");
    const appearance = {
        theme: "flat",
    };
    let options = {
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        appearance: appearance,
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (cartTotal > 0) {
            console.log(cartTotal);
            axios
                .post("/api/stripe/create-payment-intent", {
                    total: cartTotal,
                })
                .then((data) => setClientSecret(() => data.data?.clientSecret));
        }
    }, [cartTotal]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCartTotal(cart.total);
    }, [cart.total]);

    return (
        <div>
            <>
                <div className="cartPage-containerRight-title">
                    Payment Information
                </div>
                {clientSecret && (
                    <>
                        <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={options}>
                            <CheckoutForm
                                handleCart={handleCart}
                                handleValidation={handleValidation}
                            />
                        </Elements>
                    </>
                )}
            </>
        </div>
    );
};

export default PaymentGateway;
```

the code below is from CheckoutForm.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
    useStripe,
    useElements,
    PaymentElement,
    LinkAuthenticationElement,
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

const CheckoutForm = ({ handleCart, handleValidation }) => {
    const stripe = useStripe();

    const elements = useElements();
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!stripe) {
            return;
        }

        const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
            "payment_intent_client_secret"
        );

        if (!clientSecret) {
            return;
        }

        stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
            switch (paymentIntent.status) {
                case "succeeded":
                    setMessage("Payment succeeded!");
                    break;
                case "processing":
                    setMessage("Your payment is processing.");
                    break;
                case "requires_payment_method":
                    setMessage(
                        "Your payment was not successful, please try again."
                    );
                    break;
                default:
                    setMessage("Something went wrong.");
                    break;
            }
        });
    }, [stripe]);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (handleValidation()) {
            // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
            // which would refresh the page.

            if (!stripe || !elements) {
                // Stripe.js hasn't yet loaded.
                // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
                return;
            }

            setIsLoading(true);

            const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
                //`Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
                elements,
                confirmParams: {
                    return_url: "http://localhost:3000",
                },
                redirect: "if_required",
            });

            if (error) {
                // This point will only be reached if there is an immediate error when
                // confirming the payment. Show error to your customer (for example, payment
                // details incomplete)
                setMessage(error.message);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } else {
                handleCart();
                // Your customer will be redirected to your `return_url`. For some payment
                // methods like iDEAL, your customer will be redirected to an intermediate
                // site first to authorize the payment, then redirected to the `return_url`.
            }
        }
    };
    const paymentElementOptions = {
        layout: "tabs",
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="cartCheckout-paymentDetails">
            <PaymentElement options={paymentElementOptions} />
            <div className="cartCheckout-button-container">
                <button
                    disabled={isLoading && !stripe && !elements}
                    id="submit"
                    className="cartCheckout-button"
                >
                    <span id="button-text">
                        {isLoading ? (
                            <div className="spinner" id="spinner"></div>
                        ) : (
                            "Pay now"
                        )}
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {message && (
                <div
                    id="payment-message"
                    style={{ color: "red", textAlign: "center" }}
                >
                    {message}
                </div>
            )}
        </form>
    );
};

export default CheckoutForm;
```

this is the code block for the payment gateway. I want to re-render the Stripe Payment Element everytime the clientSecret changes.
Or I want to have a way to get the payment gateway to charge only the final amount in the cart and not extra.

Answer (score 0):

Once specified, you can't change the `client_secrete` passed to the Elements without remounting it.

When cart items change, you should consider updating the PaymentIntent's amount (send an update request from your backend), and call [elements.fetchUpdates()](https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/fetch_updates) to reflect the updates in the Payment Element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this integration would help:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred

This is called the 'deferred Payment Element'. Instead of creating the Intent first (which gives you the `client_secret`), you create a Payment Element instance with some params that may not be final. Only when your customer submits the form would you then create the Intent to get the `client_secret` and confirm
it using Elements.

The alternative would be what @qichuan posted above.

Comment: I did it as you said. But it doesn't update all the time.

Comment: So I guess the best option is to create a popup component with the payment Element. That wouldn't need to update the payment intent. Only to create as it is triggered only at the very last

Comment: Yes, though I may be missing some of the nuances of what you want to achieve in your build. In the scenario I'm imagining, I would use the integration above to create a Payment Element without creating a Payment Intent. If you need to update the Element, you can use *elements.update()* documented here [0]. But in most cases, I don't know that you would even need to do that - ultimately, all that matters is that changes take effect on the Payment Intent you create on the backend [0] https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/update